# Sets with the same cardinality generates isomorphic free modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a ring with 1.
Prove: If $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, then the free module generated by $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic, $F(A) \cong F(B)$.

Here is what I have done:

$|A| = |B| \implies \exists \text{ bijection }\phi:A\rightarrow B$
Then make a new function $\Phi : A \rightarrow F(B)$ such that $\phi (a) = \Phi (a)\ \forall a \in A$

By the universal property, there is an R-module homomorphism $\psi:F(A) \rightarrow F(B)$ such that $\psi(a) = \Phi(a) \forall a \in A$

Surjectivity:
$\forall b \in F(B), b = \sum^n_{i=1}r_ib_i,\ r_i \in R,\ b_i \in B, \ i = 1,..., n $
Then $b = \sum^n_{i=1}r_i\phi(a_i) = \sum^n_{i=1}r_i\psi(a_i) = \psi(\sum^n_{i=1}r_ia_i)$

I am stuck on the proof for injectivity. I don't see why $ker(\psi)$ has to be trivial. Please help.

Comment: What's the definition of generated module in this case?

Comment: analogous to "span" in vector space

Comment: A set doesn't necessarily generates a free module, just take non zero zero divisor for example.

Comment: @Hello Darkness: that is correct in general; what is happening here is that the poster is using imprecise language to refer to free modules constructed over arbitrary sets (constructed in the precise sense of the functor mentioned in the answer below).

Comment: Hmmm, okay, thanks! The way I was thinking would lead the rezult to be false. Just take 1 and the principal ideal generated by a non unit non zero divisor.

Comment: Instead of trying to directly show it is injective, find an inverse map.

Comment: @HelloDarkness : Sorry for the confusion, an R-module F is free on the subse A if $\forall x \in F, \ \exists !\  \text{non-zero}\  r_i \in R,\ a_i \in A,\ i=1,...,n,\ s.t. x = \sum_{i=1}^nr_ia_i$. Then A is a basis or set of free generators for F. In your case, PID generated by non-zero zero divisor won't work because it will violates the uniqueness part of the definition.

Comment: @William Ambrose: that is not a fully correct definition of a free module (there are some adjustments to be made for precision and rigour).

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Let me try again. An R-module F is free on the subset A if $\forall \text{non-zero}\ x \in F,\ \exists ! \text{non-zero}\ r_i \in R,\ i=1,...,n,\ \exists !a_i \in A,\ i=1,...,n,\ s.t. x = \sum_{i=1}^n r_ia_i$

Comment: when you write $r_i$ that automatically means you have a family of objects $r$ whose component at index $i$ is $r_i$ and therefore $r$ should be quantified as such, which the above formal description does not do. Using the  same notations as yours, a far more concise description is: for any $x \in F$ there exists a unique $\lambda \in R^{(A)}$ such that $x=\sum_{t \in A} \lambda_t t$. Or equivalently, the extension of the inclusion map $\mathrm{i}_{F}^{A}$ (going from $A$ to $F$) to $R^{(A)}$ yielded by the universality property of free modules is bijective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to complete what you are doing is to also consider the map going the other way.

Let $\phi\colon A\to B$ be the bijection. Then $\phi$ induces a module morphism $\Phi\colon F(A)\to F(B)$. Similarly, $\phi^{-1}$ induces a module morphism $\Psi\colon F(B)\to F(A)$.

Now consider the map $A\to F(A)$ given by $\phi^{-1}\circ\phi =\mathrm{id}$. This should induce the unique map $\mathrm{id}\colon F(A)\to F(A)$. But it also induces the map $\Psi\circ\Phi$. By the uniqueness clause of the universal property, you get that $\Psi\circ\Phi = \mathrm{id}_{F(A)}$.

Symmetrically, by considering the corresponding map $B\to F(B)$ that factors as $F(B)\to F(A)\to F(B)$ via $\Phi\circ\Psi$, you get that $\Phi\circ\Psi = \mathrm{id}_{F(B)}$. This proves that both $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are isomorphisms, and inverses of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Everything goes far smoother by considering the **covariant functor**:
$$A^{(\bullet)}: \mathbf{Ens} \to A\text{-}\mathbf{Mod} \\ X \mapsto A^{(X)} \\ f \mapsto A^{(f)}$$
where $\mathbf{Ens}$ denotes **the category of sets** and for arbitrary $f: X \to Y$ we denoted by $A^{(f)}$ the unique $A$-linear map induced via **the universality property of free modules**, in other words the unique one satisfying the relation 
$$A^{(f)} \circ \iota_X = \iota_Y \circ f$$
where $\iota_X$ represents **the canonical injection** of $X$ into the free module $A^{(X)}$ constructed over $X$.

Functors **always associate isomorphisms of the target category** (in your case isomorphisms of $A$-modules) **to isomorphims of the source category** (which in your case are bijections between sets), so with this set-up you are done in a hurry.

As an addendum to the above, there is an even more general valid statement:
$$f\ \text{injective (surjective)} \Longleftrightarrow A^{(f)}\ \text{injective (surjective)}$$

Comment: In English, the category of sets is normally denoted $\mathbf{Set}$, not $\mathbf{Ens}$.

Comment: Glad you are aware, and that this is not born of ignorance but rather of idiosincracy.  Talk of moral imperatives, though, and insinuations about requirements nobody mentioned,  seem like an utter waste of everyone’s time.

Comment: And if you want better typography, don’t use a minus sign for $\mathbf{R}$-$\mathbf{Mod}$; use a hyphen, which is what it’s supposed to be. Compare $\mathbf{R-Mod}$ with $\mathbf{R}$-$\mathbf{Mod}$ or $\mathbf{R}\text{-}\mathbf{Mod}$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: may I also add the question of how one correctly types a hyphen in math environment?

Comment: You can either leave math environment, or use `\text`. The first one above was typed as `$\mathbf{R}$-$\mathbf{Mod}$`, while the second one was `$\mathbf{R}\text{-}\mathbf{Mod}$`.

Comment: Once again, thank you!

Comment: You can’t leave math mode while in display mode, so for the display you need to use `\text`

Comment: I had the audacity of using the keyboard hyphen (in the math environment). It does produce a longer hyphen indeed.